# Converting from json array to json object not working properly

Tags: javascript, json, string

I have created a rest service like this:

```
@GET
@Path("/getsummary")
@Produces("application/json")

public Response summary()
{

        VoltDAOImpl voltDao = new VoltDAOImpl();
        Map<String ,List<HashMap<String,String>>> returnList=       voltDao.getOrderDetails("PEAKM" , "Hydra" ,
                 "" ,  voltDao.client,"notional" ,1000);
        List<HashMap<String,String>> totalSlpSummaryList = returnList.get("total_slp_summary");
        List<HashMap<String,String>> totalSlpSummaryBySideList = returnList.get("total_slp_summary_by_side");
        ObjectWriter ow = new ObjectMapper().writer().withDefaultPrettyPrinter();

            String json1 = null;
            String json2 = null;
            String json3 = null;
            try {
                json1 = ow.writeValueAsString(totalSlpSummaryList);
                json2 = ow.writeValueAsString(totalSlpSummaryBySideList);
                json3="["+json1+","+json2+"]";
                //json3 = json1 + "\n" + json2;
                System.out.println(json1);
                System.out.println(json2);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


    return Response.status(200).entity(json3).build();
}
```

And then I'm consuming this in a javascript like this:

```
var rootURL = "http://localhost:8181/RestServiceProject/rest/WebService/getsummary";
 function findBySummary() {
    console.log("inside loading grid");
    var returnval1;
     $.ajax({
         type: 'GET',
         url: rootURL,
         dataType: "json",
         async: false,
         success: function(json3){  

            returnval1 = json3;
            console.log(returnval1);

         }

     });
     return returnval1;
 }

console.log(returnval1);
```

return the following result:
[returnval1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/al7mS.png)

later I'm calling `findBySummary();` and doing the following:

```
    var json3 = findBySummary();

        var json4 = json3[0];
console.log("json4");
        console.log(json4);
        var json_temp = JSON.stringify(json4);
        console.log("json_temp")
        console.log(json_temp);
        var json_temp1 = json_temp[0];
        console.log("json temp1");
        console.log(json_temp1);
```

Following is the log output for this:
[log output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bwItk.png)

I am trying to convert json_temp, which is, :

```
[{"total_exec_qty":"286595","total_notional":"21820771.72","total_wt_arr_last_slp":"2.4364","total_num_ords":"1630","total_wt_ivwap_slp":"6.0969","total_wt_arr_slp":"1.7889","total_ord_qty":"576991"}]
```

to this(json_temp1):

```
{"total_exec_qty":"286595","total_notional":"21820771.72","total_wt_arr_last_slp":"2.4364","total_num_ords":"1630","total_wt_ivwap_slp":"6.0969","total_wt_arr_slp":"1.7889","total_ord_qty":"576991"}
```

But why am I getting `[` only for json_temp1??

Answer (score 3):

Note that `JSON.stringify(json4)` returns a string.

So, the code `json_temp[0]` will return the first element in this string.

What you want is:

`var json_temp1 = json4[0];`

and not:

`var json_temp1 = json_temp[0];`

The code below is wrong for your need:

```
var json_temp = JSON.stringify(json4);
console.log("json_temp")
console.log(json_temp);
var json_temp1 = json_temp[0];
```